# Violin plot in R binning most groups into an "other" category?

Tags: r, grouping, violin-plot

I have a dataframe that I am currently grouping by a category that I have about a thousand items in.  This creates an overly wide chart where I'm actually not interested in most of the data, since they are all alike.

What I want is to only see the plots for items that are above a threshold in their max value, and possibly combine all of the others into an "other" category.

Is there a canned way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fct_lump()` from the [forcats package](https://github.com/tidyverse/forcats) might work.

You would need to process the values to proportions first, but it has the argument `prop` which "preserves values that occur at least `prop` of the time" (it groups the rest into an "Other" level).

There is alternatively an `n`  argument for the number of levels to keep (also grouping the rest into an "Other" level).

Here's a bit [more information about forcat](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/08/31/forcats-0-1-0/)s.

Comment: This is a perfect starting point for me.  fct_lump, in particular, lets me look at the ones for which I have the most data.  I'm not sure how to look at the ones that have the highest variance in a dimension, though.  Do you know if that is doable?  And huge thanks!

Comment: Highest variance in terms of another variable?

Comment: Yes.  And I could go with something simpler like max of another variable.

Comment: Basically, if I generate 1000+ violin plots, but I really want to dive in on the ones with the highest peaks.

Comment: Probably not a canned way to do that. You could calculate these values using the `var()` or `max()`, and then select the groups with the largest mean values for them.

Comment: Again, huge thanks on this!  I think using dplyr and adding a column is exactly what I want.